# How can make watermark Renderer?

Tags: android, mobile, opengl-es

I want to make customized watermark renderer on Android.

I am going to add watermark at bottom right corner above current camera preview screen.

Here is the source code what I made. this code does not work.

Please help me. Thank you.

Function call sequence is :

-setWatermarkTexture

-createBuffers

-configureOpenGL

-draw

```
public class WatermarkRenderer implements Renderer {

    private int[] textureHandles = new int[1];

    float vertices[] = {
            -1, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,
            -1, 1,
            -0.5f, 1,

    };

    float texCoords[] = {
            0, 0,
            1, 0,
            0, 1,
            1, 1,
    };

    private Bitmap      watermark;
    private int[] buffers = new int[2];
    private float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];


    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;

    @Override
    public void configureOpenGL() {

        GLES20.glGenTextures(textureHandles.length, textureHandles, 0);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandles[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLES20.glGenBuffers(buffers.length, buffers, 0);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW );

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8, textureBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW );

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void createBuffers() {
        vertexBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(8);
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        textureBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(8);
        textureBuffer.put(texCoords);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        //GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        //GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

        if (watermark != null) {
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, watermark, 0);
            watermark.recycle();
            watermark = null;
        }
/*
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(AttributeLocations.POSITION);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(AttributeLocations.POSITION, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(AttributeLocations.TEXTURE_COORDINATES );
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(AttributeLocations.TEXTURE_COORDINATES, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4 );

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(AttributeLocations.POSITION);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(AttributeLocations.TEXTURE_COORDINATES);
*/
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProjectionMatrix(float[] projectionMatrix) {
        this.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
    }

    public void setWatermarkTexture(Bitmap bitmap) {
        watermark = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: "it does not work" isn't a question.  What do you expect to happen?  What actually happens?  What's the difference?  Is it crashing, or showing incorrect output?  If crashing what's the log?  Yu need to explain things more thoroughly

Comment: I just saw that my custom renderer class struct, and when I use above class, nothing happened. so I just want to make texture renderer that can show png watermark above video preview. FYI camera renderer already is working. but not shows watermark.

Comment: and I have updated my source code, basically I want to know what is missing on my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

Here is the source code.

```
public class WatermarkRenderer implements Renderer {

    private final float[] TEX_VERTICES = {
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f
    };
    private final float[] POS_VERTICES = {
            0.2f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,
            0.2f, -0.9f,
            1.0f, -0.9f
    };

    private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
                    "attribute vec4 a_position;\n" +
                    "attribute vec2 a_texcoord;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 v_texcoord;\n" +
                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "  gl_Position = a_position;\n" +
                    "  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;\n" +
                    "}\n";
    private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
                    "precision mediump float;\n" +
                    "uniform sampler2D tex_sampler;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 v_texcoord;\n" +
                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex_sampler, v_texcoord);\n" +
                    "}\n";

    private final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;

    private Bitmap  watermark;

    private int shaderProgram;
    private int texSamplerHandle;
    private int texCoordHandle;
    private int posCoordHandle;
    private FloatBuffer texVertices;
    private FloatBuffer posVertices;

    private int[] textureHandles = new int[1];

    @Override
    public void configureOpenGL() {

        shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, OpenGLUtils.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VERTEX_SHADER));
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, OpenGLUtils.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER));
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            String info = GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram);
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
            shaderProgram = 0;
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not link program: " + info);
        }

        texSamplerHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex_sampler");
        texCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_texcoord");
        posCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_position");
    }

    @Override
    public void createBuffers() {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer;

        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEX_VERTICES.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        texVertices = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        texVertices.put(TEX_VERTICES);
        texVertices.position(0);

        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(POS_VERTICES.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        posVertices = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        posVertices.put(POS_VERTICES);
        posVertices.position(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {

        // Select the program.
        GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

        // Set the vertex attributes
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texVertices);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(posCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, posVertices);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(posCoordHandle);

        // Set the input texture
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandles[0]);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(texSamplerHandle, 0);

        GLES20.glGenTextures(textureHandles.length, textureHandles, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandles[0]);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, watermark, 0);

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(texCoordHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(posCoordHandle);

        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProjectionMatrix(float[] projectionMatrix) {
    }

    public void setWatermarkTexture(Bitmap bitmap) {
        watermark = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is applicable on recorder video ?? if yes then please let me know.

Comment: YES, it's possible to add to video